# UITableViewcontroller Subclass need to apply Padding left and Right

Tags: ios, uitableview

i have one class with a subclass of UITableViewcontroller where I am displaying `Tableview` i want to display with left-right padding, can anyone please throw some light on how to apply padding on `Tableview`

i am using this subclass of `UITableview` 
https://github.com/amkomatz/EXTable

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could always create a `UIViewController` and manually add a `UITableView` to it.. that way you can control the layout precisely.

like for example inside `viewDidLoad()` of a regular `UIViewController` subclass:

```
let tableView = UITableView(/* use whichever init makes sense */)
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self

tableView.registerCellForReuse... // I forget the exact syntax off the top of my head

self.view.addSubview(tableView)

// set constraints (auto layout) as normal
```

However, if you really want to use `UITableViewController` you can just add some `contentInset` (aka padding):

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: leftPadding, bottom: 0, right: rightPadding)
```

Comment: how to control frame from subclass

Comment: its not possible to adjust the frame of the table view on a `UITableViewController` it would be like making the `view` of any other VC smaller than the screen (root views of a view controller will always stretch to edge of screen)